# Animated Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have been going through this [website](http://www.snapwiz.com/), I was wondering how to implement a scroll like this. I mean background picture is changing and you can see front image sliding nicely.

Same type of effect I saw at [Apple Inc Website.](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/) Here if you scroll down, in middle of the page you see an image of iPhone getting separated from a lot and joining another one while scrolling. I just started learning jquery. Can anyone suggest me how to implement this type of animation as I am not sure how to search for such effect. Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another plugin for it, probably a bit more options and designed to work also in old browsers such as IE 9 or IE 8 (OnePageScroll doesn't) and which I believe is essential nowadays.

It is called **[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**

I believe it will fit you better.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple website uses functionality similar to [OnePageScroll](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/18/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/).

Comment: I you want compatibility and a few more options, [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) will work under IE 8.